# Catching exceptions in django templates

Tags: python, django, exception, django-templates

I'm using a template tag in a Django template (the tag is `thumbnail`) and it's throwing an exception that makes the template fail with a 500 error. I would like to stop this from happening, as I don't have complete control over the source images that sporadically trigger this exception, and use a blank/placeholder image instead in those cases. This is the current template code:

```
{% thumbnail video.image_url "50x74" crop="center" as im %}
<img src="{% cdn_images im.url %}" />
{% empty %}
<img src="/media/img/noimage_thumb.png" alt="" />
{% endthumbnail %}
```

This is the exception (PIL throws it):

```
TemplateSyntaxError at /

Caught IOError while rendering: cannot identify image file
```

I searched for solutions and came up with [silent_variable_failure](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#render) which is a property that, if defined, makes an Exception be quiet. I guess this may point in the right direction but as far as I can tell any solution using this would mean I'd have to modify the template tag code itself, which is an external library - I'd prefer not to do that,

Ideally I would like to replace the third line in my code with something like `{% empty or exception_raised %}`.

Does anything like that exist? Do you know of any alternatives?

Comment: django template errors seem to fail silently, it's strange that the `thumbnail` tag does not follow this same convention.  I think normal django behavior would be failing silently.

Comment: @dm03514 - yes, that's true. It feels like a bug to me. Perhaps I should report it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The way I've always handled this is to push it up to the model layer.  So in your model:

```
  class MyImageModel(model.Model):
       # model fields go here..

       def get_url(self):
            try:
                 # or whatever causes the exception
                 return self.url
            except IOError:
                 return None
```

And in your template:

```
{% thumbnail video.image_url "50x74" crop="center" as im %}

{% if im.get_url %}
    <img src="{% cdn_images im.get_url %}" />
{% else %}
    <img src="/media/img/noimage_thumb.png" alt="" />
{% endif %}

{% endthumbnail %}
```

Comment: That's reasonable, thanks. I'll probably do this and then report the behaviour of the `thumbnail` tag upstream.

Answer (score 0):

Your template should not be raising an exception as a normal course of action. If there's an error in the template, you fix it. Otherwise, anything that could potentially raise an exception should be handled in the model or the view. There's no tag like you mention for a reason.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But my template hasn't got an error as far as I can tell. I guess the `thumbnail` tag is just at fault here.